# Replacing all tokens based on properties file with ANT

Tags: ant, tokenize

I'm pretty sure this is a simple question to answer and ive seen it asked before just no solid answers.

I have several properties files that are used for different environments, i.e xxxx-dev, xxxx-test, xxxx-live

The properties files contain something like:

```
server.name=dummy_server_name
server.ip=127.0.0.1
```

The template files im using look something like:

```
<...>
   <server name="@server.name@" ip="@server.ip@"/>
</...>
```

The above is a really primitive example, but im wondering if there is a way to just tell ANT to replace all tokens based on the properties file, rather than having to hardcode a token line for each... i.e

```
<replacetokens>
   <token key="server.name" value="${server.name}"/>
   <token key="server.ip" value="${server.ip}"/>
</replacetokens>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify the properties file from which to read the list of tokens for the ['replace' task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) using `replacefilterfile`:

```
<replace file="input.txt" replacefilterfile="properties.txt"/>
```

Similarly, in a filter chain, you can use ['replacetokens' `propertyfile`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacetokens):

> This will treat each properties file
>   entry in sample.properties as a
>   token/key pair:

```
<loadfile srcfile="${src.file}" property="${src.file.replaced}">
  <filterchain>
    <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
      <param type="propertiesfile" value="sample.properties"/>
    </filterreader>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this if you need properties to come from > 1 different property file?  The only way I know is to create a new file which concatenates the file together - do you know of a better way?

Comment: @MarkRhodes - Sorry for the delay ... I can't think of anything that isn't equivalent to concatenating.  It should be simple enough to do that though.  Replacetokens doesn't support a file set for the replacements.

Answer (score 2):

With the replace task by itself I missed the @ delimiters around tokens so I came up with the following solution. You can use any ant property in the template file

```
<project name="replace" default="replace">

<property file="build.properties" />
<target name="replace">

    <!-- create temp file with properties -->
    <tempfile property="temp.replace" suffix=".properties"/>
    <echoproperties destfile="${temp.replace}" />
    <!-- replace name=value with @name@=value -->
    <replaceregexp file="${temp.replace}" match="([^=]*)=" replace="@\1@=" byline="true" />

    <!-- copy template and replace properties -->
    <copy file="template.txt" tofile="replaced.txt" />
    <replace file="replaced.txt" replacefilterfile="${temp.replace}" />

</target>
```

with a template

```
ANT home @ant.home@
ANT version @ant.java.version@
server name @server.name@ ip @server.ip@
```

this results in

```
ANT home /usr/share/ant
ANT version 1.7
server name dummy_server_name ip 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) form [`ant-contrib`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3) you can read the tokens form properties file and replace multiple tokens over multiple files.

```xml
<project name="MyProject" default="replaceToklens" basedir=".">
    <property name="profilesProperties" value="${basedir}/environment.properties" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>

    <!-- File to Load/ Accessable -->
    <property file="${profilesProperties}" /> 
    <target name="replaceToklens">
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
            <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
            <filter filtersfile="${profilesProperties}" />
            <copy todir="${build.dir}" filtering="true" overwrite="true">
                <fileset dir="${basedir}"> <!-- target/MyProject -->
                    <include name="*.xml" />
                    <exclude name="build.xml" />
                </fileset>
            </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

folder structure:

```
ANT
 \_ build.xml
 \_ environment.properties
 \_ server.xml
 \_ build
        \_ server.xml   [replaced with token value]
```

In order to replace single toke use the following:

```xml
<replace file="build/server.xml" token="@keyName@" value="${keyValue}" />
```