# Ant: Replace all tokens in a file, with its values from a property file

Tags: ant

I am writing an ant script that replaces all tokens in a file by getting its values from another file.
For instance, the file a.properties contains tokens,

```
server.url=@SERVER.URL@
application.id=@APP.ID@
etc...
```

And the values for the tokens should be fetched from a single file, say token.properties which contains the below entries

```
SERVER.URL=http://localhost:80
APP.ID=HelloWorld
```

I want to accomplish this without mentioning the replacefilter for each token. I have tried searching in the web for this and couldn't figure out. Is this possible in ant?

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html

Comment: I think this is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508122/replacing-all-tokens-based-on-properties-file-with-ant

Comment: @JavaChap, I tried that and I am having a hard time getting it to work.

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that replaces values in server.properties based on values.properties.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Token Replacement" default="default">

   <target name="default">
      <replace file="server.properties" replacefilterfile="values.properties"/>
   </target>

</project>
```

server.properties - file that needs to binded

```
user.firstName=$firstName 
user.lastName=$lastName
user.company=$company
```

values.properties - the properties from this file will be used for replacement

```
$firstName=John
$lastName=Doe
$company=Acme
```