# Maven install:install-file : specified file not exists

Tags: maven, jar, installation, pom.xml

I tried to add custom jar into my project (to pom.xml). When I made an operation

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<myGroup> -DartifactId=<myArtifactId> -Dversion=<myVersion> -Dpackaging=<myPackaging> -DlocalRepositoryPath=<path>
```

I actually received an error: the specified file  not exists. But the file is in the folder - that's the problem. How I can resolve this? Or how I can add custom jar without this step? I know about scope , but it's not working properly - maven variable ${basedir} cannot be used in systemPath.

Maven 3.3.9

UPDATE 1: Actually, now I find smth new: Maven doesn't like dots in groupId and version. After some tries I installed file, but it's wrong path, because instead of (e.g) org.my.local.file tree I received file in org_my_local_file folder in maven repo.

Comment: What did you specify for `<path-to-file>`? What is the actual location of the file on disk?

Comment: I ran this command from general module's folder, that's why path to file is only his name. And error was, that file in this folder doesn't exist, but he is :)

Comment: specify in `<path-to-file>` .jar in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this many times and it worked as expected.
What do you exactly mean with :

> Maven doesn't like dots in groupId and version.

What exception do you get ?
You get org_my_local_file because I think you exachanged '.' in the groupId against '_' ?

You find a good tutorial here where you can see how it is done correctly :

[How to include custom library into maven local repository?](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

**EDIT :**
It looks like you are using windows. Especially powershell is known to cause problems. Have a look here, may be you have to escape some characters, there are some possible solutions :

[install maven artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442230/how-to-manually-install-an-artifact-in-maven-2)

Comment: So. my command exactly was 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=modules\mylib.jar -DgroupId=org.mylib -DartifactId=my-lib -Dversion=1.7 -Dpackaging=jar.
After that I received error: 
Unknown lifecycle phase ".mylib".

Comment: Saved my day by "Especially powershell is known to cause problems. "

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to initialize our base development environment.  We use an Ant script to initialize Maven, our developer server and other tools and includes installing a few 3rd party jars into the local Maven repository.  This error, "The specified file `'<path>\true'` not exists" was occurring when invoking Maven from within Ant 1.9.11.

I also used this answer to specify paths identified in the Ant script and set them in the batch script template before running the batch script.
Specifically, this answer offered a lot to get the batch script constructed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36298099/2336934.  Didn't take much:

```
    <!--  generate the batch file -->
    <tempfile property="temp.file" suffix=".properties" deleteonexit="true" destdir="${env.TEMP}" />
    <echoproperties destfile="${temp.file}" />
    <replaceregexp file="${temp.file}" match="([^=]*)=" replace="@\1@=" byline="true" />
    <copy file="${basedir}/scripts/install-jars.template" tofile="${basedir}/scripts/install-jars.bat" />
    <replace file="${basedir}/scripts/install-jars.bat" replacefilterfile="${temp.file}" />

    <echo message="Running batch file for Maven setup" />
    <exec executable="${basedir}/scripts/install-jars.bat" />
    <delete file="${basedir}/scripts/install-jars.bat" deleteonexit="true" />
```

There weren't any issues with the parameters being passed, but this must be specified correctly.  Running the command you're trying to execute in a script temporarily in a command window is useful to verify the command syntax and function before trying to embed in a script.

I even created a empty `true` file to satisfy the error which complained the file was not a valid POM file.  Filling it with basic POM content led to another error.  So reader beware, this business about "true not exists" is a Red Herring.

Moving the Maven `install:install-file` commands out to the batch file was the key to get past the issue.  It also allowed me to specify the quotes in the command as `"` rather than `&quot;` due to the commands originally being specified in the Ant script (xml).