# Why mvn install Oracle JDBC ojdbc6 Jar always has 'No plugin found for prefix' error, and fail mvn build?

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc

I follow the below two links to download ojdbc jar and install it locally in Windows system:

1. [Oracle JDBC ojdbc6 Jar as a Maven Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898499/oracle-jdbc-ojdbc6-jar-as-a-maven-dependency)
2. [Maven install:install-file : specified file not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449276/maven-installinstall-file-specified-file-not-exists)
3. https://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg83991.html

I end up using below command (use ` to escape -):

```
 mvn install:install-file `-Dfile=C:\Users\xxx\ojdbc6.jar `-DgroupId=com.oracle `-DartifactId=ojdbc6 `-Dversion=11.2.0.2.0 `-Dpackaging=jar `-DgeneratePom=true
```

but I am still getting below errors:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '`-Dfile=C' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\peter\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

Also, although it looks like by doing above, ojdbc jar is installed under .m2/repository, when I run mvn install to the project, I am still getting:

```
Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to execute `mvn` from folder where jar is located not to use full path with drive name?

Comment: @Ivan yes, same behavior

Comment: Try to enter your command and specify your path to mvn: `C:\apache-maven\bin\mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\xxx\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting backquotes (`) in your command? Try to run it without backquotes.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\xxx\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
:install-file (default-cli) on project xcept-test: The specified file 'C:\Users\
xxx\Downloads\ojdbc6.jar' not exists -> [Help 1]

Comment: as explained in my 2nd link, in windows cmd window, if you do not add backtick, you will see the above error. it happens in powershell too.

Comment: Did you try it out without backquotes in a basic cmd? Your link only speaks of Powershell, actually...

Comment: yes. i actually tried in basic cmd, though the article said it applies for powershell. Same behavior.